# Show different icon for first and different icon for remaining objects in html Angular8

Tags: html, arrays, angular, typescript, angular8

Hi I have an array = `ideasArray` It has a total of 6 objects. In HTML I want to show different icon against idea of first object and different icon for the rest of the objects.

```
<div class="container" *ngIf="let idea of ideasArray">
<ul class="data">
<li class="header"><i class="fas fa-medal"></i>Top Recommended Idea<li>
<li class="header"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>Recommended Idea<li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to show different icon for first object (TOP RECOMMENDED IDEA) and rest all will have same icon (RECOMMENDED IDEA). How can I do it. From `ideasArray` the first element is always Top Recommended Idea so its header should show a medal and rest all should show a thumbsup. How can this be achieved?

```
for (let j = 0; j < finalData.length; j++){
if(j<3){
this.firstThree.push(this.finalData[j]);
this.receivedData = this.firstThree;
} else if ((j >= 3) && (j <6)) {
this. nextThree.push(this.finalData[j]);
this.receivedData = this.nextThree;
}
}
```

Comment: You can use `index` for your `*ngFor` (not `*ngIf` by the way). Then if `index=0` you'll skip assigning the icon.

Comment: can you show me how would it fit in this code? Because I am not sure how can I give index=0 in <li> tag  and also why not use ngIf ?

Comment: Also, if index=0 I do not want to skip assigning the icon. I want to assign a different icon.

Comment: Which part do you want to do the iteration the `ul` tag or `li` tag?

Comment: in <li> tag I want to check if it is first plan give medal else a thumbsup

Comment: if I give *ngIf="let idea of ideasArray; let i = index"
<ul class="data">
<li class="header{{i}}"><i class="fas fa-medal"></i>Top Recommended Idea<li>
<li class="header{{i}}"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>Recommended Idea<li>
</ul>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be to use use ngIf structural directive for this purpose. You can use it with index of the array like this :-

```
<div class="container" *ngFor="let idea of ideasArray; index as i">
<ul class="data">
<li *ngIf = "i == 0" class="header"><i class="fas fa-medal"></i>Top Recommended Idea<li>
<li *ngIf = "i != 0" class="header"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>Recommended Idea<li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all `*ngIf` is to display element based on some condition. You need to use `*ngFor` for iteration or looping

```
<div class="container" *ngFor="let idea of ideasArray; index as i">
   <ul class="data">
     <li *ngIf = "i == 0" class="header"><i class="fas fa-medal"></i>Top Recommended Idea<li>
    <li *ngIf = "i != 0" class="header"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>Recommended Idea<li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

To understand more on how to use `structural directives` please refer to [Angular Structural Directive](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It is almost correct. Just one thing, I have a carousel so 6 objects are shown on 2 pages. 3 each. Now it is applying the same styling to first object of both the pages. I want only on 1st object on 1st page to be getting top recommended plan

Comment: I am writing the logic by updating the code. Can you tell me how to avoid that?

Comment: If you're working on two different components, that's the way to do it.